# Qt: linking errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, static-linking

I'm new to Qt and I'm receiving the following errors while linking my project:

```
    qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': va
    lue '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in main.obj
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::
    _Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::
    _Syserror_map(int)" (?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xbad_al
    loc(void)" (?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xout_of
    _range(char const *)" (?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlength
    _error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) publ
    ic: static void __fastcall QListData::dispose(struct QListData::Data *)" (__imp_
    ?dispose@QListData@@SIXPAUData@1@@Z)
    main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) publ
    ic: static int __fastcall QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@S
    IHXZ)
    moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllim
    port) void __fastcall qt_assert(char const *,char const *,int)" (__imp_?qt_asser
    t@@YIXPBD0H@Z)
    mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport
    ) public: static class QString __fastcall QCoreApplication::translate(char const
     *,char const *,char const *,int)" (__imp_?translate@QCoreApplication@@SI?AVQStr
    ing@@PBD00H@Z)
    mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport
    ) public: static void __fastcall QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(class QObject *
    )" (__imp_?connectSlotsByName@QMetaObject@@SIXPAVQObject@@@Z)
    d:\c\output\main\main32.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
```

This is my linking command:

```
    "%VCInstallDir%\bin\link.exe" /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:"%VCInstallDir%\lib"  /LIBPATH:"%VCInstallDir%\atlmfc\lib" /LIBPATH:"%WindowsSdkDir%\Lib\win8\um\%_pf%" LIBPATH:"e:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib" /MERGE:code=.text /errorReport:none /DEBUG /FIXED /INCREMENTAL:NO /NXCOMPAT /LTCG /MAP:"d:\c\temp\main\win32\main.map" MAPINFO:EXPORTS /NODEFAULTLIB /NOLOGO /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO /DYNAMICBASE:NO /OUT:"d:\c\output\main\main32.exe" /MANIFESTUAC:NO /SAFESEH:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /VERSION:1.0 /WX /MERGE:.rdata=.text /FIXED:NO libcmt.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib shlwapi.lib shell32.lib secur32.lib psapi.lib ole32.lib gdi32.lib comctl32.lib ws2_32.lib crypt32.lib wininet.lib msxml2.liboleaut32.lib netapi32.lib userenv.lib comdlg32.lib mpr.lib uuid.lib Qt5Core.libQt5Gui.lib Qt5Widgets.lib qtmain.lib libEGL.lib libGLESv2.lib "d:\c\temp\main\win32\main.obj" "d:\c\temp\main\win32\moc_mainwindow.obj" "d:\c\temp\main\win32\ui_mainwindow.obj" "d:\c\temp\main\win32\mainwindow.obj"
```

Are there some missing libraries or other dependencies? Thank you.

Comment: Are you mixing compiler versions? You must use a Qt build for your exact compiler version otherwise you can and will have problems..

Comment: I'm using VS2012 linker with Qt 5.0.2 x32 VS2010 version since I didn't find x32 version for VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Qt library built with another version of VS. Compile Qt using your compiler.

Comment: Ok, I've compiled Qt from source with VS2012 (wit /MT parameter), but the linker error is still there. How to fix it?

Comment: If that linker error is still there then you are not using the libraries that you compiled but still somehow using the incompatible libraries you installed from the binary package. Remove those and fix your library paths.